# Why conformal map of $\mathbb R^n$ taking $H^n$ onto $H^n$ will take $\partial H^n$ into itself?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry

Picture below is from the 175th page of [do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry](https://library.lol/main/0A30B69FEAD8267DB0705B4F81764346). I don't know how to get the red line of first picture below.

$H^n=\{(x_1,...,x_n):x_n>0\}$ is the upper half-space.

What I try: assuming there is $q\in\partial H^n$ such that $h(q)\notin \partial H^n$, if $h(q)\in H^-=\{(x_1,...,x_n):x_n<0\}$, then there is sequence $q_n\rightarrow q$ such that $q_n\in H^n$ and $h(q_n)\rightarrow h(q)\in H^-$. Therefore, there must be some point $p\in H^n$ such that $h(p)\in H^-$, namely $h(p)\notin H^n$, this is contradict with $h$ take $H^n$ onto $H^n$.

But for the case $h(q)\in H^n$, I don't know how to prove it. I feel it  will be contradict with conformal.

> [image]

> Definition of conformal
> [image]

Comment: The underlined sentence does not use the fact that $h$ is conformal. It is used afterwards to compute some angle. Another property is used for $h$ here, presumably that it is a homeomorphism or a diffeomorphism

Comment: You should quote the theorem 7.5 that do Carmo is proving: It is about conformal transformations, and transformations are normally assumed to be invertible.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Sorry, where is the theorem 7.5. I fail to find it in do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry.

Comment: @Didier  I check it, but there is not assuming about homeomorphism or  diffeomorphism.  The reason why I think conformal works is because in the second case, there might be a contradiction with conformal. Give me some time to think about the details of this thing.  I have attached a link to do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry in above problem. You can have a look if you're interested (I'm mainly worried about whether I missed it, because my English is not good). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Theorem 5.3, not 7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's clean up do Carmo's treatment of the Luoiville Theorem. The correct statement of Theorem 5.2 is:

Suppose that $n\ge 3$, $U\subset S^n= R^n\cup \{\infty\}$ is a **connected** open subset and $f: U\to S^n$ is a conformal mapping. Then $f$ equals the restriction of a **Moebius transformation** of $S^n$.

[Here a Moebius transformation is a self-diffeomorphism of $S^n$ which is a composition of inversions. Equivalently, it is a composition of Euclidean isometries, Euclidean dilations  (both extended to $S^n$) and inversions (at most one of each.]

With this formulation, the *conformal map $h$* appearing in the proof of Theorem 7.5 you are referring to, is the restriction of a self-diffeomorphism of $S^n$. Hence, for each subset $W\subset S^n$, $h$ maps boundary points of $W$ to boundary points to $h(W)$.

Comment: Why do I see different theorem 5.2 than yours. I have add the link of the book I read in above problem. There is not $S^n$ and self-diffeomorphism.  And seemly, I am not referring to Theorem 7.5.    Maybe we got the wrong version of the book ?  But anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @EnhaoLan: There is no $S^n$ in do Carmo because he is formulating Liouville's theorem incorrectly. One can blame it on him following uncritically the book by Dubrovin-Novikov-Fomenko where the same mistake is made.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wouldn't have suspected it was wrong if you hadn't told me, since that  first case is proved  made me think it was right. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Quite generally, if $X$ is a topological space, $f:X\to X$ a homeomorphism, and $A\subset X$ a subspace, then $f$ maps $\partial A$ to $\partial f(A)$.

Comment: But just conformal $h$ is.

Comment: What is your definition of conformal?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven  I have add the definition of coformal in above problem.